# Как передать GET запрос из ссылки, но не обновлять страницу?

Tags: javascript

Если просто вернуть `false`, то ничего не происходит.

Подскажите, пожалуйста: как можно обновлять `GET` параметры в адресной строке, но не обновлять страницу?

Answer (score 1):

Передрано отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Пример:

```
function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
     document.title = response.pageTitle;
     window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath);
 }
```

Затем вы можете использовать `window.onpopstate`, чтобы обнаружить навигацию по кнопкам "назад/вперед":

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = e.state.html;
        document.title = e.state.pageTitle;
    }
};
```

Подробнее о работе с историей браузера см. материал MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history